# How to remove columns/rows having empty value?

Tags: r

I have 3 columns.
type <- Tv show, Movie,Movie
title <- Norm of the North: King Sized Adventure,Jandino: Whatever it Takes,Transformers Prime
director <- Richard Finn and Tim Maltby
The 3rd column has only one value(i.e director).
How to remove those rows with empty values?

Comment: `?na.omit` and `?complete.cases` will probably help.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove the rows with empty cells is this:

Illustrative data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  type = c("Tv show", "Movie", "Sitcom"),
  title = c("Norm of the North", "King Sized Adventure","Whatever it Takes"),
  director = c("Richard Finn", "Tim Maltby", "")
)
```

First, transform empty cells to `NA`:

```
df[df==""] <- NA

df
     type                title     director
1 Tv show    Norm of the North Richard Finn
2   Movie King Sized Adventure   Tim Maltby
3  Sitcom    Whatever it Takes         <NA>
```

Then, remove rows with `NA` using `na.omit`:

```
na.omit(df)
     type                title     director
1 Tv show    Norm of the North Richard Finn
2   Movie King Sized Adventure   Tim Maltby
```